# Editing and Saving user HTML with Javascript - how safe is it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

For example I have a **Javascript-powered form creation** tool. You use links to add html blocks of elements (like input fields) and TinyMCE to edit the text. These are saved via an autosave function that does an AJAX call in the background on specific events.

The save function being called does the database protection, but I'm wondering if a user can manipulate the DOM to add anything he wants(like custom HTML, or an unwanted script).

**How safe is this**, if at all?

*First thing that comes to mind is that I should probably search for, and remove any inline javascript from the received html code.*

Using PHP, JQuery, Ajax.

Comment: All the answers seem correct, but I'll go with the community Upvote count for the best one. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not safe at all. You can **never trust the client**. It's easy even for a novice to modify DOM on the client side (just install Firebug for Firefox, for example).

While it's fine to accept HTML from the client, make sure you validate and sanitize it properly with PHP on the server side.

Comment: This is a pretty good library if you need to sanitise user input HTML : http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 1):

Are you saving the full inline-html in your database?
If so, try to remake everything and only save the nessesary data to your backend. **ALL** fields should also be controlled if they are recieved in the expected way.

All inline-js is easily removed.

You can **never** trust the user!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely unsafe, unless you take the steps to make it safe of course. StackOverflow allows certain tags, filtered so that users can't do malicous things. You'll definately need to do something similar.

I'd opt to sanitize input server side so that everyone gets their input sanitized, whether they've blocked scripts or not. Using something like this: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3746-PHP-Remove-unsafe-tags-and-attributes-from-HTML-code.html or http://grom.zeminvaders.net/html-sanitizer implemented with AJAX would be a pretty good solution