# What is the standard to stop browser dev tool editing to bypass disabled elements?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, standards

I've been in a few situations now where it seems a browsers dev tools and the ability for anyone to freely view/edit/add had the potential for something undesirable to happen.

Example one... 
A button that has an event, that triggers a function, that may run ajax, which runs a php script that may communicate with your database... User goes to dev tools, removes disabled tag from the html, and the button can freely trigger the button.

Example two...
Ok, continue from example one, but lets say that the programmer just completely removes the button from the html, instead of disabling it. What stops a user that understands dev tools from going in and just creating a `<button id="whatever">Do Bad Things</button>`  if a function already exists in the "viewable" source code javascript that anything can view to find the event trigger they want to, determine how its triggered, and then match that with the added html button. (is this possible, it seems possible, I could be wrong.)

I guess I am just curious if there is a standard to prevent these types of things to happen, especially in the case where users don't want a button completely removed, they would prefer the button is viewable, just not usable.

Is it bad code if you don't protect against this? or is it necessary to completely protect yourself from all ends, by adding logic that double or even triple checks in your php scripts to ensure that things are not being bypassed by unwanted measures? I mean, I know its obvious to protect your php with logic as well, but is there a standard to follow, or best practice to prevent these types of scenarios?

Any information would likely be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you can't "completely protect" against all contingencies - that's impossible. if it wasn't no one would ever get hacked. but you should - within reason - protect your stuff.. for example, don't make buttons that alter your database unless there is an active session belonging to someone with permission to do so.

Comment: Relying on data from 'your frontend' should not be relied on, the backend should always check that what your asking it to do is valid.  You can't catch everything, but you can ensure major things don't go wrong (loosing money is a major one)

Comment: Simply, You can't. You can just disable right click through `JS` or can disable `F12` through JS but still there are workarounds. so It's better to validate through server.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I appreciate the feedback. I have also found some more material on this while searching after I posted and from what I've read it is definitely never safe to trust the client. Always protect your php. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research and the replies here I was able to determine that the client side is never really safe from manipulation. Although adding protection client side can be useful, it is not a means of true safety. You MUST 100% validate server side as well to be protected. Thanks.

Similar posts I found that had more comments/answers I was able to read from.

[Stackoverflow1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329698/editing-and-saving-user-html-with-javascript-how-safe-is-it?rq=1)

[Stackoverflow2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903794/can-firebug-or-developer-tools-use-to-hack-a-web-site?rq=1)